# Java: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver'?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am currently working on a maven project but every time i try to deploy my war i get the exception below:

```
ERROR [DispatcherPortlet:276] Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed;  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransforme r)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1097)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:661)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.createPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:356)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletBean(FrameworkPortlet.java:268)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.GenericPortletBean.init(GenericPortletBean.java:120)
```

I simply don't understand when i have everything in place properly why this error. Please checkout my declaration in POM.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            <argLine>
                 -javaagent:"path\spring-instrument-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar"
            </argLine>
            <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please guide.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: Note also that the `spring-aspects` module JAR must be present on the classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using tomcat bundle and to enable `load-time-weaving` in Tomcat add [Spring Instrument Tomcat](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-instrument-tomcat/) to Tomcat's `lib` directory and the following in the `context.xml` inside the `META-INF` directory of your tomcat:

```
<Context path="/test">
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
</Context>
```

Refer to the [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-environments) on the tomcat's configuration.

*Note: The configuration for tomcat differs based on the version.*

Comment: I tried all that you said but it still displays the same error.

Comment: are you trying to run your webapp using tomcat version?

Comment: @Shirish refer the spring documentation in link and follow the steps mentioned there to configure the tomcat

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/520058/Spring/AspectJ-LTW-Spring a similar problem @Shirish

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help ..i solved it finally.. A few changes were not required..i have edited your answer..once it gets approved i will accept your answer..Cheers.!!

Comment: you can update in your question what other else you have done to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Though this question was asked long time back, I am still answering it. Somebody else might find it useful. 
If you are using Tomcat try adding the following in the catalina.bash for windows or catalina.sh for linux servers:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -javaagent:"C:\path\to\spring-instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"
```

Keep in mind it will work only in Tomcat versions less than 7.0.55. After that it wont take it. And you will need to add it in the context.xml as mentioned here load-time-weaver (aspectj-weaver) is not working in apache tomcat 7.0.55.